# recognizes & learns persons and objects

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want my robot to recognize the object and if the object has appear for first time then ask about it and then saves it and next time he comes with the same object he should recognise it and speak up its name stored. pls guide me with the direction. what should i do ?????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52453/recognizes-&-learns-persons-and-objects/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think here is not the proper place for asking this question, Object Recognition is a general issue.

there is lots of different algorithm for object recognition, as an first step i recommend you to have a look at texture matching algorithms like SURF and Sift. there is lots of sample codes if you google them.
And also for Object Segmentation Purposes you can have a look at PCL library samples.

For Speech Recognition you can use PocketSphinx,

For TTS you can use festival package,

GoodLuck

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2